# How do I run a docker private registry with letsencrypt in ubuntu.18.04

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt

I am trying to get a docker private registry running on a server.
I am running Docker version 18.06.1-ce build e68fc7a for this setup both server and test client.

(Note: I replaced the real domain with my.domain.com in all code below)

From bits and pieces of blogs my config.yml for the registry is now the below.

```
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
http:
  addr: :5000
  host: https://my.domain.com
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
  tls:
    letsencrypt:
      cachefile: /etc/docker/registry/letsencrypt.json
      email: me@my.domain.com
auth:
  htpasswd:
    realm: basic-realm
    path: /etc/docker/registry/htpasswd
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3
```

I run the container for the registry with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run -d -p 5000:5000 \
-p 443:5000 \
--name test-registry \
-v /var/lib/docker/registry:/var/lib/registry \
-v /etc/docker/registry/config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml \
registry:2
```

The log shows this when starting:

```
docker logs -f docker-registry
time="2018-10-23T01:56:51Z" level=warning msg="No HTTP secret provided - generated random secret. This may cause problems with uploads if multiple registries are behind a load-balancer. To provide a shared secret, fill in http.secret in the configuration file or set the REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET environment variable." go.version=go1.7.6 instance.id=82c8a49d-58d2-4429-b8c2-fa67f3d64617 version=v2.6.2
time="2018-10-23T01:56:51Z" level=info msg="redis not configured" go.version=go1.7.6 instance.id=82c8a49d-58d2-4429-b8c2-fa67f3d64617 version=v2.6.2
time="2018-10-23T01:56:51Z" level=info msg="Starting upload purge in 37m0s" go.version=go1.7.6 instance.id=82c8a49d-58d2-4429-b8c2-fa67f3d64617 version=v2.6.2
time="2018-10-23T01:56:51Z" level=info msg="using inmemory blob descriptor cache" go.version=go1.7.6 instance.id=82c8a49d-58d2-4429-b8c2-fa67f3d64617 version=v2.6.2
2018/10/23 01:56:51 [INFO] acme: Registering account for me@my.domain.com
time="2018-10-23T01:56:52Z" level=info msg="listening on [::]:5000, tls" go.version=go1.7.6 instance.id=82c8a49d-58d2-4429-b8c2-fa67f3d64617 version=v2.6.2
```

When I access it from outside I get added to the log:

```
2018/10/23 01:59:56 [INFO][my.domain.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate
2018/10/23 01:59:56 [INFO][my.domain.com] acme: Could not find solver for: http-01
2018/10/23 01:59:56 [INFO][my.domain.com] acme: Could not find solver for: tls-alpn-01
2018/10/23 01:59:56 [INFO][my.domain.com] acme: Could not find solver for: dns-01
2018/10/23 01:59:56 http: TLS handshake error from 70.36.174.194:43028: map[my.domain.com:[my.doman.com] acme: Could not determine solvers]
```

I have seen a number of posts that indicate some challenge methods are no longer supported by letsencrypt also a lot of posts about similar issues. And lots of out of date bug reports. I saw nothing in the latest docker docs about selecting or enabling disabling challenge types for letsencrypt.

I am looking for a way to get this working.

Comment: apparently it is a bug where the canned letsencrypt implementatin in the registry image is out of sync with letsencrypt.  For now I manually generated the certicificate on the host machine and mounted the files in the registry.

This works but doesn't automatically refresh things when the letsencrypt certificates expire.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/2839